# Can't click "Ask Question" when on the "Ask a Question" page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface, navigation

There's an inconsistency with the way the top navigation works when the user is on one of the pages pointed to by those buttons. For the five buttons on the left, being on the page doesn't change the behavior of the button; it's still a link and clicking it will take you back to the same page again:

[image: Screenshot of the top navigation with the mouse on Questions]

[image: Screenshot of the top navigation with the mouse on Tags]

I find that behavior useful if I'm on a tab and want to open another tab at the same location; I just middle-click the button.

However, the **Ask Question** button doesn't act the same way; when you're on the Ask a Question page the button isn't clickable:

[image: Screenshot of the top navigation with the mouse on Ask Question]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20091213143147/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/pages/1722-general/suggestions/19576-ask-question-buttom-erases-your-current-question)

> If you ask a question and type in your Title and Question then accidentally hit the "Ask Question" button at the top instead of "Ask Your Question" at the bottom, your question is lost and hitting the back button does not get your original text back.

Comment: Wouldn't you get the "you've started writing a post, are you sure you want to leave" dialog?

Comment: regardless, people think it's the "CLICK HERE TO SUBMIT FORM" button, so it has to be disabled during /ask

Comment: Pity the stackoverflow.uservoice.com page above is now dead, while an excerpt has been helpfully provided, would have been good to see all content.